# mysql query update on joins

Tags: sql

I am trying to update table1 but its giving me errors

I have 3 tables in join. here is my sql

```
update `table1` 
set 
p.`status` = 0
from table1 t
left join
table2  p
on
p.id = t.id
join
table3 h
on
h.id =  p.id
WHERE p.`status`=1 AND h.id <>12";
```

Comment: what errors? Can you let us know what they are?

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: `h.id <>12";` probably `h.id <>'12';`

Comment: Shouldn't the `SET` be right before the `WHERE`?  See http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html .  According to that blog you don't need the `FROM` with MySQL, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong Syntax. Here it is corrected:

```
update `table1` t
left join
table2  p
on
p.id = t.id
join
table3 h
on
h.id =  p.id
set p.`status` = 0
WHERE p.`status`=1 AND h.id <>12";
```

Comment: your missing the table1 alias t

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update `table2` p
left join `table1` t on
p.id = t.id join
table3 h on
h.id = p.id
set p.`status` = 0
WHERE p.`status`=1 AND h.id <>12
```

You were saying update table1 but p.status is table2. Or you have a typo and it was suppose to be t.status.